# Encryption and decryption problem. what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question. What is wrong with my code? I made two versions to maybe get it right but its still not working. This python program should generate a password, "encrypt" a password or "decrypt" a password. I know its not real encryption but I wanted to try to do something to this because I wanted to manifest the basics and maybe learn some new stuff. But now when I encrypt and decrypt my password then only half of the letters are correct. Disclaimer: I am pretty new into python so if you could help me or give me some tips then please help me. Thank you!

Here is the code:
version 1

```
import random as rd
def psw_encryption():
  str_list = str.maketrans({"a": "b","6": "b","m": "c","g": "d","n": "e","l": "f","y": "g","e": "h","i": "k","h": "j","o": "k","v": "l","z": "m","t": "n","0": "o","d": "p","r": "q","q": "r","f": "s","u": "t","j": "u","c": "f","k": "w","i": "x","a": "z","5": "z","4": "9","s": "5","x": "3","8": "5","9":"6","3": "2","7": "9","p": "0", "8": "x"})
  print("What is your password?")
  psw = str(input())
  psw_new = psw.translate(str_list)
  print("Your encrypted password is: ",psw_new + "di29ens92ned")
  print("If you want to decrypt it then just use the decrypter.")
def psw_decrypt():
  str_list = str.maketrans({"b": "a","b": "6","c": "m","d": "g","e": "n","f": "l","g": "y","h": "e","k": "i","j": "h","k": "o","l": "v","m": "z","n": "t","o": "0","p": "d","q": "r","r": "q","s": "f","t": "u","u": "j","f": "c","w": "k","x": "i","z": "a","z": "5","9": "4","5": "s","3": "x","5": "8","6":"9","2": "3","9": "7","0": "p", "x": "8"})
  print("what is your encrypted password?")
  psw = str(input())
  psw = psw.replace("di29ens92ned", "")
  psw_old = psw.translate(str_list)
  print("Your decrypted password is:", psw_old)
def psw_gen():
  abc123_list = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"]
  print("Your Super Secret password is:",''.join([rd.choice(abc123_list) for _ in range(13)]))

print("What do you want to do?")
print("1/ Generate a Super Secret password.")
print("2/ Encrypt your password.")
print("3/ Decrypt your password")
choice_ = int(input("Put your choice here: "))

if choice_ == 1:
  psw_gen()
elif choice_ == 2:
  psw_encryption()
elif choice_ == 3:
  psw_decrypt()
else:
  print("Invalid input!")

list2 = ["b 6 m g n l y e h o 1 v z t 2 0 d q r f u j c k i a 5 4 s x 8 9 3 7 p"]
#1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

version 2

```
import random as rd #7bqia

def psw_encryption():
    str_list = str.maketrans("ba6mglnyehovzt20dqrfuicka549sx8973p", "bzcdjklmnot0rqfujhievx58936psawygzd")
    print("What is your password?")
    psw = input()
    psw_new = psw.translate(str_list)
    print("Your encrypted password is:", psw_new)
    print("If you want to decrypt it then just use the decrypter.")

def psw_decrypt():
    str_list = str.maketrans("bzcdjklmnot0rqfujhievx58936psawygzd", "ba6mglnyehovzt20dqrfuicka549sx8973p")
    print("what is your encrypted password?")
    psw = input()
    psw_old = psw.replace("di29ens92ned", "")
    psw_old = psw_old.translate(str_list)
    print("Your decrypted password is:", psw_old)

def psw_gen():
    abc123_list = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p",
                   "a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"]
    print("Your Super Secret password is:", ''.join([rd.choice(abc123_list) for _ in range(13)]))

print("What do you want to do?")
print("1/ Generate a Super Secret password.")
print("2/ Encrypt your password.")
print("3/ Decrypt your password")

choice_ = int(input("Put your choice here: "))
if choice_ == 1:
    psw_gen()
elif choice_ == 2:
    psw_encryption()
elif choice_ == 3:
    psw_decrypt()
else:
    print("Invalid input!")
```

I already tried many things but nothing worked.

Comment: Why did you include two versions of the code?  Which one should we use?

Comment: I am so sorry. The first one is the main one. I just wanted to show that I also tried "other" methods, but I am not good in python so both didn't work.

Comment: I noticed str.maketrans() has only lowercase letters, If you have tried with Uppercase doesn't work. May I know what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried it with lowercase letters and numbers.  Like every third letter or so can't convert correctly.

Comment: If I want to covert for example: qwertyuiop, then I will get rwhqngtxkdi29ens92ned as the encrypted one, but when I want to decrypt it I get: qkertyu8o. This is all now based on the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionaries you are passing as arguments to `maketrans()` have duplicate keys, which is not allowed.

For example, in `psw_encryption()`, the dictionary has both `"8": "5"` and `"8": "x"`.  But dictionaries can't have duplicate keys; the first one is discarded and the second one takes its place.  So in this case, "8" will always be translated to "x"; it will never be translated to "5".

And there are several other duplicates as well, in both functions.

So, to put it simply, your encryption rules do not match up with your decryption rules.